# Type or namespace of interface cannot be found; not sure what's missing

Tags: c#, reference, namespaces, handler, using

I have two handlers, ArticleIndexer.ashx and MediaHighlightsIndexer.ashx. To create MediaHighlights, I copied ArticleIndexer and replaced "article" with "highlght," they're that similar (the only difference between the two is the properties of the Article data object and of the MediaHighlight data object). When I tried to run MediaHighlightsIndexer.ashx, I got this error:

"The type or namespace name 'IMediaHighlightDao' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?')

but ArticleIndexer.ashx does not have this problem and runs correcly.

Where would this problem be occurring? Would this be an issue in the handler, or an issue in MediaHighlightDao.cs? All of the MediaHighlight files are in the same folders as the Article files, and they all have the same references.

here's the interface:

```
using MITSloan.Common.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MITSloan.Common.Dao
{
    public interface IMediaHighlightDao
    {
        IEnumerable<MediaHighlight> GetHighlights(Int64 categoryId);

        MediaHighlight GetHighlight(Int64 highlightId);

        MediaHighlight GetHighlight(Int64 highlightId, string html);
    }
}
```

and here's the handlerl:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="MediaHighlightIndexer" %>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Ektron.Cms;
using Ektron.Cms.Framework;
using Ektron.Cms.Framework.Organization;
using MITSloan.Common.Dao;
using MITSloan.Common.Model;
using MITSloan.Data.Dao;
using MITSloan.Search;

public class MediaHighlightIndexer : IHttpHandler {

    private IndexManager _indexManager;
    public IndexManager IndexManager
    {
        get { return _indexManager ?? (_indexManager = new IndexManager()); }
    }

    private static IMediaHighlightDao _mediaHighlightDao;
    public static IMediaHighlightDao MediaHighlightDao
    {
        get { return _mediaHighlightDao ?? (_mediaHighlightDao = new MediaHighlightDao()); }
    }

    private static FolderManager _folderManager;
    public static FolderManager FolderManager
    {
        get { return _folderManager ?? (_folderManager = new FolderManager(ApiAccessMode.Admin)); }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        string core = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["core"]) ? context.Request["core"] : "offline";

        var metadata = new Dictionary<string, object>(1);
        var folderHighlights = GetHighlightsByFolderId();
        foreach (var f in folderHighlights)
        {
            metadata["folderId"] = f.Key;
            IndexManager.IndexHighlights(f.Value, metadata, core);
        }
        IndexManager.IndexCommit(core);
        context.Response.Write("Success");
    }

    private Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<MediaHighlight>> GetHighlightsByFolderId()
    {
        long highlightFolderId;
        if (!Int64.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ektron.highlightFolderId"], out highlightFolderId))
        {
            return new Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<MediaHighlight>>();
        }

        //temporary hardcoded folderID for dev folder
        highlightFolderId = 471;

        FolderData highlightFolder = FolderManager.GetTree(highlightFolderId);
        if (highlightFolder == null )
        {
            return new Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<MediaHighlight>>();
        }


        // get highlights in highlights folder
        Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<MediaHighlight>> rv = new Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<MediaHighlight>>();
        var highlights = MediaHighlightDao.GetHighlights(highlightFolder.Id).ToList();
        rv.Add(highlightFolder.Id, highlights);

        //// in case there are folders within the highlights folder, get those too
        //foreach (var f in highlightFolder.ChildFolders)
        //{
        //    highlights = highlightDao.Gethighlights(f.Id).ToList();

        //    rv.Add(f.Id, highlights);
        //}

        return rv;

        //return highlightFolder.ChildFolders
        //    .ToDictionary(f => f.Id, f => highlightDao.Gethighlights(f.Id));
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: We have no idea what the problem could be until you post some code. Can you post all or some of the contents of MediaHighlightsIndexer.ashx? Is there a C# Code-Behind for this file as well?

Comment: Are you using the correct name space at the top for that interface in the file throwing the error? Something like "using some.namcepace;"? Some code would help.

Comment: I added the code for the interface and the handler. i can post more of the files if you need them.

Comment: Sometimes problems like this are indicative of a problem in another project not building correctly. Can you build the DAO project by itself? How about the dependent projects? You might also try to do a clean and build on the solution.